# Pyspark- No JSON object could be decoded while spark streaming, when reading a text file with multiple json

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read a text file with multiple JSON similar to the below format-

```
{"availableDocks": 32, "totalDocks": 39, "city": "", "altitude": "", "stAddress2": "", "longitude": -73.99392888, "lastCommunicationTime": "2017-04-24 03:14:09 PM", "postalCode": "", "statusValue": "In Service", "testStation": false, "stAddress1": "W 52 St & 11 Ave", "stationName": "W 52 St & 11 Ave", "landMark": "", "latitude": 40.76727216, "statusKey": 1, "availableBikes": 2, "id": 72, "location": ""}
{"availableDocks": 3, "totalDocks": 33, "city": "", "altitude": "", "stAddress2": "", "longitude": -74.00666661, "lastCommunicationTime": "2017-04-24 03:12:49 PM", "postalCode": "", "statusValue": "In Service", "testStation": false, "stAddress1": "Franklin St & W Broadway", "stationName": "Franklin St & W Broadway", "landMark": "", "latitude": 40.71911552, "statusKey": 1, "availableBikes": 30, "id": 79, "location": ""}
```

The code below code was used

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
import json
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 60)
streams=ssc.textFileStream('hdfs:///test_data')

parsed = streams.map(lambda v: json.loads(v))  
def getSqlContextInstance(sparkContext):
    if ('sqlContextSingletonInstance' not in globals()):
        globals()['sqlContextSingletonInstance'] = SQLContext(sparkContext)
    return globals()['sqlContextSingletonInstance']
def process(time, rdd):
    print("========= %s =========" % str(time))
    try:
        # Get the singleton instance of SparkSession
        sqlContext = getSqlContextInstance(rdd.context)

        # Convert RDD[String] to RDD[Row] to DataFrame
        #using spark 1.3 hence jsonRDD which is believe is similar to read.json?
        df = sqlContext.jsonRDD(rdd)

        # Creates a temporary view using the DataFrame

        print df.show()
    except Exception as e:
    print "in exception"
    print str(e)
        pass

parsed.foreachRDD(process)
ssc.start()  
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

However, I am getting no JSON object could be decoded when I run this code.
I have used JSON lint and checked if both the json are in proper format

Comment: The file is not valid JSON. It must not contain multiple top level objects. If the JSON objects are devided by line breaks, you can read by line and decode every line. I also like to know what the purpose of the `globals()` hack is. It looks evil.

Comment: I obtained the code from the spark streaming documentation. Not sure what globals() are. But if you had to correct the JSON file how would you do it? I am new to programming, what is multiple top level objects? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Json Data:**

```
{"timestamp": "1571053218000","t1": "55.23","t2": "10","t3": "ON"}

{"timestamp": "1571053278000","t1": "63.23","t2": "11","t3": "OFF"}

{"timestamp": "1571053338000","t1": "73.23","t2": "12","t3": "ON"}

{"timestamp": "1571053398000","t1": "83.23","t2": "13","t3": "ON"}
```

## Pyspark Code to read from above json data:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, LongType, DecimalType,StructType, StructField, StringType
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)

stream_data = ssc.textFileStream("/filepath/")

def readMyStream(rdd):
  if not rdd.isEmpty():
    df = spark.read.json(rdd)
    print('Started the Process')
    print('Selection of Columns')
    df = df.select('t1','t2','t3','timestamp').where(col("timestamp").isNotNull())
    df.show()


stream_data.foreachRDD( lambda rdd: readMyStream(rdd) )
ssc.start()
ssc.stop()
```